# i want to show a different image when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i need to make it that when i click the button an image is replaced by another

HTML:

```
function Show1(){
        if(Clicked === false) setClicked(true);
        else setClicked(false);
        console.log(Clicked)
    }




<div className="SignIn__AsWhat">
          <button className="SignIn__AsStudent" onClick={Show1}> 
          {Clicked === 0? <"What do i put here"/> : <"and here?"/>}                
          Je suis étudiant
          </button>
              <button className="SignIn__AsTeacher">
              Je suis enseignant
              </button>
          </div>
```

Comment: Where you wanna exactly place the image? inside the button?

Comment: No i have another div in my code containing the image and i need to change that if you know how i would appreciate itt

Answer (score 1):

```
function Show1(){
    setClicked(!Clicked)
}


<div className="SignIn__AsWhat">
      <button className="SignIn__AsStudent" onClick={Show1}> 
      {Clicked? <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-aepjQbk-blQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rc0BHkpnTpc2qD0-hwjIvLM-8o8BQ/mo/photo.jpg?sz=48"/> : <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izu1b.jpg?s=64&g=1"/>}                
      Je suis étudiant
      </button>
          <button className="SignIn__AsTeacher">
          Je suis enseignant
          </button>
      </div>
```

Comment: It Workeedd but i need to change an image in another div is there a way i can do that?